# Calculate ROC probability for highy correlated variables

Tags: probability, roc, independence

The usual assumption of i.i.d. is made with such frequency that it risks being applied to things like difference of correlations for highly dependent (correlated) variables. To calculate dependent correlation probability [Stinger 1980](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/1980-08757-001), [pdf](http://www.psychmike.com/Steiger.pdf), [online calculator](http://www.psychmike.com/dependent_correlations.php) is frequently cited (5181$\times$ on Google Scholar as of today). The same is true for receiver operator characteristic curves, that is, the assumption of independent ROC curves risks being made for highly correlated variables with the result that significant differences can be falsely discarded. Is there an equivalent probability calculation method analogous to Stinger 1980 for application to significance of difference between two dependent ROC curves, i.e., curves that are so not independent that even slight differences are significant?

I came across a post for which odds ratios for dependent ROC curves were discussed, I want a probability calculator if there is one, please.

Comment: H-measure might be more suited in this setting, see Papers of [Hand](https://www.hmeasure.net/papers.html).

Comment: @patagonicus Perhaps, but I do not see how. How does this address covariance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Calimo What I was fishing for and not expressing very well was that a test of proportions for receiver operator characteristic (ROC) curves should be more powerful than DeLong et al. Indeed, [An extended McNemar test for comparing correlated proportion of positive responses](https://medcraveonline.com/BBIJ/BBIJ-08-00281.pdf) as applied to ROC curves shows that "In comparison to other tests, extended McNemar test statistic is a very suitable alternative having the highest statistical power among the analysis carried out and so has the capacity to discriminate between diseased and non-diseased subjects in a better way."

This in effect recommends [StAR: a simple tool for the statistical comparison of ROC curves](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-9-265) by Vergara et al.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your premise that i.i.d. is often made when comparing dependent ROC curves is unfounded. Seminal papers by Hanley or DeLong have explicit terms to account for covariance between the variables.

DeLong expresses the covariance of two correlated ROC curves as:

[image: Formula for the covariance of two ROC curves]

Hanley calculates a critical ratio $z$ which takes the correlation $r$ between the two variables into account.

[image: Formula of a critical ratio z]

These papers are highly cited, and are the basis for all such comparisons to date. They do not make the i.i.d. assumption, but explicitly address it.

**References:**

- Elisabeth R. DeLong, David M. DeLong and Daniel L. Clarke-Pearson (1988) "Comparing the areas under two or more correlated receiver operating characteristic curves: a nonparametric approach". Biometrics 44, 837-845.
- James A. Hanley and Barbara J. McNeil (1982) "The meaning and use of the area under a receiver operating characteristic (ROC) curve". Radiology 143, 29-36.

Comment: Thanks for the references, I've been looking for something like that. As for the i.i.d. assumption, it is frequently inappropriate, for example, in the medical literature.

Comment: However, the DeLong paper is very highly cited. +1

Comment: Yes I agree the i.i.d. assumption is frequently made, but my point is, not in this context. I tried to clarify.

Comment: OK. The next problem is then possibly that the ROC nonparametric difference method is insensitive to actual differences. Perhaps we should be doing a Fisher exact test, or something else more powerful.

Comment: Problem or feature, depending on what your data looks like and what you're actually trying to achieve. Sure if your data has iid you can do a Fisher exact test, but I'm not sure why you'd even mention it here.